# Python: file count recursivly but not getting accurate count

Tags: python

Why result following Unix command and python are different ?

**Using find command**

```
rahul@home-pc:~$ find /opt/ -type f | wc -l
1331
```

**Using Python 2.7.3**

```
In [31]: sum([len(f) for p,d,f in os.walk('/opt/') ])
Out[31]: 1340

In [32]: t=0

In [33]: for p,d,f in os.walk('/opt'):
             t = t + len(f)

In [34]: t
Out[34]: 1340
```

So how to get accurate count using python ?

Update 1#
find and os.walk , also count hidden file

```
root@home-pc:~# touch /opt/.xxx
root@home-pc:~# find /opt/ -type f | wc -l
1332
root@home-pc:~# find /opt/ -type f | grep .xxx
/opt/.xxx
root@home-pc:~# python -c "import os; print sum([len(f) for p,d,f in os.walk('/opt/')])"
1341
```

Update 2# 
both tool are also count hard link

```
root@home-pc:~# ln /tmp/t /opt/abc
root@home-pc:~# find /opt/ -type f | wc -l
1333
root@home-pc:~# python -c "import os; print sum([len(f) for p,d,f in os.walk('/opt/')])"
1342
```

Update 3# 
Thanks to @thefourtheye, answer is correct os.walk count soft link as normal file :

```
root@home-pc:~# ln -fs /tmp/test_f /opt/test_f
root@home-pc:~# find /opt/ -type f | wc -l
1333
root@home-pc:~# python -c "import os; print sum([len(f) for p,d,f in os.walk('/opt/')])"
1343
```

Comment: I think python version takes into account hidden files as well, whereas your unix command does not. I mean hidden files and folders that start with a `.` infront of them.

Comment: I had check that, find command also count hidden file, see http://paste.ubuntu.com/6565480/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.walk` considers soft links also as normal files, whereas `find` doesn't consider soft links as normal files. Thats why you see difference in the count.

To get consistent count, change the find command like this

```
find /opt/ -type f -follow
```

And Use `followlinks = True` in `os.walk`, like this

```
os.walk("/opt/", followlinks = True)
```

Comment: I genuinely did not know this! +1 mate

Comment: thanks, but how to get accurate file count with Python, or is it accurate ?

Comment: I had cross check with `-P` follow symlink and `-L` never follow symlink, still not found, see http://paste.ubuntu.com/6565506/